# Multidimensional output in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to train a neural network that has a vector output?
Docs for `pandas_input_fn` state that

```
x: pandas DataFrame object.
y: pandas Series object. None if absent.
```

So `y` is only one-dimensional. How can I make `y` a vector?
In scikit-learn, for example, `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.fit` accepts multidimensional `y`.

Comment: Yes it is. Fully-Convolutional networks typically output a multidimensional vector for example.

Comment: How? input_fn explicitly requires y to be one-deminsional, it raises an exception otherwise.

Comment: Don't use pandas or use a different class. Here's a guide for tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers